# Finding the dimension of a handle

Tags: general-topology

'If M is a manifold together with a (k-1) sphere embedded in its boundary .... we attach a k handle...' - mathworld.wolfram.com/Handle.html

The figure in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_decomposition
 says "A 3 ball with three 1 handles attached."

A 2-1 sphere is embedded in the boundary of the three ball, so shouldn't it be a 2 handle instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $3$-ball, $M$, is a $3$-manifold, a solid ball.  The handles you see in the image are $1$- handles, $I \times D^2$.  The boundary of each handle is a pair of $D^2$s, one on each end which are attached to the boundary of $M$, and an $S^1 \times I$ which is not attached to $M$.  Each such handle is attached along two disks in the boundary, $\partial M$, so that attachment map $f$ has image $S^{1-1} \times D^{3-1} \simeq S^0 \times D^2$, the disjoint union of a pair of $2$-disks, which you can see actually is the attachment region in the boundary of the $3$-ball.